# Planck length paradox

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, physical-constants, discrete

This is a paradox I thought of a few days ago, and I wanted to ask whether it makes any sense and where the mistake is.

We know that the nothing but light can move faster than light itself. So in a Planck time, the only thing that can move a Planck length is light itself. So every other thing can move less than a Planck length in a Planck time, but since a Planck length is the smallest length, nothing other than light can move in a Planck time.

But since every period of time is composed of some Planck times, nothing but light can move. Because that clearly isn't what we expect, it is a paradox.

What went wrong?

Comment: This is yet another incarnation of Zeno's paradox which was resolved a long time ago. For some [resolutions, see other Physics.SE posts](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=zeno%27s+paradox).

Comment: "planck length" is just a scale (10^-34 [m]), like talking in meters (10^0 [m])about things that are human size. This scale produced by combining some physical constants (including planck constant from which it got it's name) in order to get something with dimentions of length. You too may play with physical constants, produce something with dimention of length and call it after your name.

Comment: @KyleKanos No, I don't think it is the same as Zeno's paradox. In my opinion, we can refute Zeno's paradox by saying that it isn't legal to talk about lengths smaller than the Planck length. That approach won't work here.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I can, but the paradox will still hold if I define $l_{Wythagoras}$ as the smallest possible length. For the paradox we don't need to know that the Planck Length is about 1.6x10^-35 [m].

Comment: @wythagoras: The Planck length has no physical significance, so Error 1 is asserting it has physical significance, which leads you straight back to Zeno's paradox.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm afraid I don't really understand, would you be so kind to explain is some more?

Comment: There is no indication that distance has a granularity at any scale. And, no, asserting that the plank length represents the finest measurement that can be made (true to within the validity of current theory) does ***not*** imply quantization of space.

Comment: What's not to understand? Planck scales don't quite mean what you think it means, thus you shouldn't put much weight into it. In light of that, your question really is a repetition of Zeno's paradox.

Comment: What "went wrong" is that neither space or time are discrete due to currently accepted theories, so deriving a paradox from the assumption that they are is *not* a physics question (and merely shows that discretization of time and space would not be compatible with the classical idea of motion and speed, which is not surprising).

Comment: @ACuriousMind In other words, the step where I divide the time into some Planck lengths is not valid. Am I right to say so?

Comment: The question could have been answered several times in the length of time it took for this comment chain. Come on chaps, cut the gabble and get answering.

Comment: I do not think this question should have been put on hold. The OP has misunderstood the significance of the Planck length and time, i.e. they have interpreted it to mean spacetime is discrete, but it remains a perfectly good question and a perfectly good answer is to point out that spacetime is not discrete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Planck length isn't the smallest possible length, and the Planck time isn't the smallest possible time. As far as we know spacetime is continuous so velocities do not have to be an integral number of Planck lengths divided by an integral number of Planck times.

The Planck length is the smallest length that can be measured, but the reason we can't measure any lengths smaller than this is because it would take so much energy to do so that the system would form a black hole a Planck length in size. We couldn't measure smaller lengths because they'd be inside the event horizon and hidden from us. A similar argument explains why we can't measure times shorter than a Planck time. So our measuring abilities have a granularity, but this does not necessarily mean that spacetime does.

I should add the usual cautionary note that physics at the scales of a Planck length is not understood, so you should regard anything said about it as speculation and/or rather ambitious extrapolation.